# Dockerise rails/redis/sidekiq/postgres project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, redis, sidekiq

I'm trying to dockerize a rails app utilizing sidekiq,icecast and redis for streaming. Currently stuck on an error I've been searching to figure out for quite some time now. 
Error backtrace:

```
Successfully built 64c7adaf977d
Successfully tagged radiofm20_sidekiq:latest
Recreating radiofm20_radiofm_1 ... 
Recreating radiofm20_radiofm_1 ... done
Attaching to radiofm20_sidekiq_1, radiofm20_radiofm_1
sidekiq_1  | 2018-01-17T23:43:11.163Z 1 TID-6x26s INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.0.5 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-1"}
sidekiq_1  | getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:210:in `getaddrinfo'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:210:in `connect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:293:in `connect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:334:in `establish_connection'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:99:in `block in connect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:98:in `connect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:363:in `ensure_connected'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in process'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in `logging'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `process'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:185:in `call_pipelined'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:155:in `block in call_pipeline'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:153:in `call_pipeline'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:2353:in `block in multi'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:2345:in `multi'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:184:in `block in raw_push'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `handle_interrupt'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block in with'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `handle_interrupt'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `with'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:183:in `raw_push'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:74:in `push'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:143:in `client_push'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:87:in `perform_async'
sidekiq_1  | /app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
sidekiq_1  | /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:257:in `require'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:257:in `boot_system'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:54:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:29:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:29:in `<main>'
radiofm20_sidekiq_1 exited with code 1
radiofm_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:328:in `establish_connection'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:99:in `block in connect'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:98:in `connect'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:363:in `ensure_connected'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in process'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in `logging'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `process'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:185:in `call_pipelined'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:155:in `block in call_pipeline'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:153:in `call_pipeline'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:2353:in `block in multi'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:2345:in `multi'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:184:in `block in raw_push'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `handle_interrupt'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block in with'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `handle_interrupt'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `with'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:183:in `raw_push'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:74:in `push'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:143:in `client_push'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:87:in `perform_async'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
radiofm_1  |     from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
radiofm_1  |     from config.ru:in `new'
radiofm_1  |     from config.ru:in `<main>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
radiofm_1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
radiofm_1  |     from /app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
radiofm_1  |     from bin/rails:3:in `load'
radiofm_1  |     from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
radiofm_1  | => Booting Puma
radiofm_1  | => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
radiofm_1  | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
radiofm_1  | Exiting
radiofm20_radiofm_1 exited with code 1
```

docker-compose:

```
  radiofm:
    build: 
      context: "./"
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-development
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    env_file:
      - './src/.env'
    environment:
      - REDIS-URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  sidekiq:
    command: sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml.erb
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/src'
    env_file:
      - './src/.env'
volumes:
  postgres: 
  sidekiq:
```

Dockerfile(Kind of a mess,bear with me)

```
FROM ruby:2.4.3

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES curl-dev build-base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils

RUN wget -qO - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
  apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  postgresql-client-9.6 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*t
# Node.js
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# for nokogiri
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev


# for capybara-webkit
RUN apt-get install -y libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev xvfb


#For Ruby-shout
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2 libxslt1-dev python-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
RUN apt-get install -y vorbis-tools
RUN apt-get install -y libshout3-dev 


#Icecast
RUN  sh -c "echo deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/xiph/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./ >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/icecast.list"
RUN apt install wget
RUN  wget -qO - http://icecast.org/multimedia-obs.key |  apt-key add -
RUN  apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install icecast2




RUN rm -rf /var/lib/gems/2.4.1/cache/*
#ICECAST DEPENDENCY INSTALL REDIS+DEPENDENCY ICECAST
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
RUN redis-server --daemonize yes
# RUN redis-server --version
RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY /src /app


RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install rake
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD rails db:create 
CMD rails db:migrate
CMD rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

How can I possibly fix this getaddrinfo error? My thought are that it's some kind of connection error between sidekiq and redis.
I also have this in my sidekiq.rb config file

```
 Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379' }
    end
```

Thanks in advance.Sorry if my post is kind of ambiguous. Feel free to ask anything. :)

EDIT: I got the base Rails app to deploy(Could listen to it on port localhost:3000) with this sidekiq.rb file but now I get this error

```
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:210:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
```

The sidekiq.rb file:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379' }
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379'}
end

RadioWorker.perform_async
TestWorker.perform_async
JazzWorker.perform_async
```

UPDATE: Fixed the redis error Now facing problems with dockerizing POSTGRES
With the app running on localhost:3000 I get this error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7buGT.jpg

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.6'
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    labels:
      description: "Postgresql Database"
      service: "postgresql"
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes  
  web:
    build: 
      context: "./"
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-development
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    env_file:
      - './src/.env'
    environment:
      - REDIS-URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - POSTGRES-URL=postgres://postgres:5432/
    depends_on: 
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

Comment: Could you post the full docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Is redis in the same docker-compose?

Comment: @whites11 yes here you go I must have ommited the services and version nothing else:
 version: "3.0"
 services:

Comment: @Robert I don't have a separate image for redis in the docker-compose file I install it through Dockerfile development at line 47 
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
RUN redis-server --daemonize yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile is for building images, not for running daemons. The result of a docker build is a static thing (docker image). I recommend you to run redis directly from the docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
  image: redis

radiofm:
  (...)
  depends_on: redis
  (...)
```

Similar case for  PostgreSQL. If you really what to setup your image for running daemons when container starts, you should tune CMD with a script or so.

Also, you can only use CMD just once.

Comment: Ok If I try it like this:
docker-compose: https://pastebin.com/NFF2Ee6c
I get this error: https://pastebin.com/Ypzt58qw

Comment: Thanks a lot.Fixed it.Now I'm having problems with the postgresql image I did it following your example.But I can't seem to make a connection. Check out the updated info :)

Comment: Changed the host:localhost in my database.yml to host:postgres and now I'm getting a database "development_db" does not exist